# Ensuring minimum distance between choices

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import random, collections, time, os

# pseudo-randomly select element from table 
# ensuring minimum distance before the same
# element is selected again

def choice_gen(choices, min_dist):
    last_choices = collections.deque()
    while 1:
        choices = set(choices)
        c = random.choice(list(choices - set(last_choices)))
        new_min = int(len(choices)*6/10)
        if min_dist == new_min:
            last_choices.pop()
        min_dist=new_min
        last_choices.append(c)
        choices = yield c
```

I've kind of edited this generator, the minimum distance follows this proportion:

```
len(choices):min_dist = 10:6
```

When the value given by the result of the proportion for new_min `int(len(choices)*6/10)` changes, the deque goes increase in size of one element by not popping. 
Then, until the new_min changes again, it keeps popping, thus ensuring the constant size of the deque.
At least, that's what it should do. Is my implementation right?

Comment: Your syntax error is easy to spot: no `:` after the `if min_dist == new_min` line.

Comment: You're right, I keep forgetting to add these... Well, the algorithm still has some issues I'm trying to figure out, but thanks another time for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import random, collections

# pseudo-randomly select element from table 
# ensuring minimum distance before the same
# element is selected again

def choice_gen(choices, min_dist):
    last_choices = collections.deque()
    choices = set(choices)
    while 1:
        c = random.choice(list(choices))
        choices.remove(c)
        last_choices.append(c)
        if len(last_choices) == min_dist:
            choices.add(last_choices.popleft())
        yield c
```